# How to find a connected subgraph with highest average node value and contain certain node from a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Consider the following scenario:
There is a dungeon with many connected rooms, each room contains 1 monster and some treasure. with the whole structure of the dungeon and the value of treasure in each room known, how can we find a strategy to maximize the treasure gain per monster?

Formally, we consider a undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, node weights $w\in R^V$ and a root node $r\in V$, the goal is to find a connected subgraph (or a tree, as edges weight is not important) $G'=(V',E')$ such that $r\in V'$ and the average node weight $\frac{\sum_{v\in V'} w_v}{|V'|}$ is maximized.

The problem seems related to rooted maximum weight connected subgraph problem (RMWCS), but we care about the average weight instead of the sum. The RMWCS problem is NP-hard as I survey, not sure if the average score.

The problem can be practical in several computer games where users may choose to continue exploring or just reset the map. So heuristic strategies are also welcomed.

---

I solved the actual problem I met by implementing a algorithm that solves RMWCS using integer linear programming. I use the algorithm to get the maximum total gain for every possible node count, the by comparing the mean value i can find the best one.

However, this requires running the algorithm for $|V|$ times, and adapting the ILP solution to this problem is not possible as it does not allow variable division. still wondering if there is a way that can be more efficient.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you mean by maximize the treasure gain per monster? Are there different number of treasures for different rooms? Do some monsters don't have any treasures? Are different monsters different hard to "beat" (is that important for your question/problem)?

Comment: @RaoulLuqué Different room may have different number of treasure, and all these numbers are known before exploring.  All monsters are considered the same, I added them to this scenario only to emphasis that returning to an explored room does not increase the cost (as the monster has already be defeated), so that the optimization target is the sum of treasure from all explored rooms divided by the number of rooms explored.

Comment: @RaoulLuqué I believe whether a room is of 0 or negative treasure is not important, as we can make every node non-negative by simply adding a large number to them. the average node value of every subgraph will increase by the same amount so their rank should not change.

Comment: Assuming you actually care about the question explicitly stated in the title, I think the solution is easy: find the node with the maximum "value", and consider the subgraph consisting of exactly that one node. Assume for a moment that all node values are different...then increasing your subgraph from that one node will necessarily reduce the average value. This makes me think that you really want to ask a different question, and need to think about it some more.

Comment: @JohnHughes you're right. I didn't notice that. so the problem is trivial without the condition "the subgraph must contain certain node". I will go edit the problem.

Comment: I guess talking about average vertex weight you mean division by $|V'|$ rather then by $|V|$

Comment: @Smylic thanks for pointing out, edited

Comment: Do you have a particular instance in mind?

Answer (score 3):

When a root node is specified, the problem becomes NP-hard; here is a reduction from SAT.

Given a SAT instance with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses, we design the following dungeon:

1. For each clause, there is a room with a *clausebeast* containing one unit of treasure.
2. For each variable, there is a room with a *vardragon* containing two units of treasure.
3. To each vardragon, we assign two minions: a *truegoblin* and a *falsegoblin*. The truegoblin and falsegoblin live in rooms adjacent to their vardragon's room, and those are the only ways to get to that vardragon. They carry no treasure. (If this unfairness bothers you, go ahead and give each goblin a copper coin, while ensuring that a "unit of treasure" is high enough to make the copper coin irrelevant.)
4. For every clause $C$, the corresponding clausebeast's room is also adjacent to some of the goblin rooms. Specifically, if $C$ contains the literal $x_i$, we join that room to the $i^{\text{th}}$ truegoblin's room; if $C$ contains the literal $\neg x_i$, we join that room to the $i^{\text{th}}$ falsegoblin's room.
5. Finally, your starting room just contains a single rat, to prove your mettle as an adventurer. The starting room contains no treasure, but it's adjacent to all $2n$ of the goblin rooms.

If the SAT instance has a satisfying assignment $\alpha$, then you can do the following. First, slay the rat. Then, for each variable $x_i$, if $\alpha$ sets $x_i$ to true, then kill the $i^{\text{th}}$ truegoblin; otherwise, kill the $i^{\text{th}}$ falsegoblin. Either way, you've opened up a path to the $i^{\text{th}}$ vardragon; go ahead and defeat it. Finally, because $\alpha$ is a satisfying assignment, you've opened up a path to every clausebeast, so go ahead and slaughter them all, you murderhobo.

In the end, you've gathered all $2n+m$ units of treasure in the dungeon, while encountering $2n+m+1$ monsters: $n$ vardragons, $n$ goblins, $m$ clausebeasts, and one rat. Your average profit per monster is $\frac{2n+m}{2n+m+1} = 1 - \frac1{2n+m+1}$ unit of treasure.

A lesser adventurer than you, who does not have a SAT solver at their disposal, might attempt a different strategy. Suppose that another strategy involves defeating $a$ of the vardragons and $b$ of the clausebeasts. In order to get to these vardragons, the other adventurer must also have dealt with $a'$ goblins, where $a'$ is at least $a$. Finally, the other adventurer also defeated the rat in glorious battle. So the other adventurer's average profit is $\frac{2a+b}{a+a'+b+1} = 1 - \frac{1 + (a'-a)}{2a+b+1 + (a'-a)}$. Let's assume that the other adventurer did *not* find a satisfying assignment, so either $b<m$ (they left a clausebeast alive) or $a'>a$ (they killed both the truegoblin and the falsegoblin guarding at least one vardragon).

First, note that $\frac{1+(a'-a)}{2a+b+1 + (a'-a)} \ge \frac{1}{2a+b+1}$: killing extra goblins is never profitable. So the other adventurer earns at most $1 - \frac1{2a+b+1}$ per monster. Second, because $a \le n$ and $b \le m$, $2a+b+1 \le 2n+m+1$, so $1 - \frac1{2a+b+1} \le 1 - \frac1{2n+m+1}$. Finally, since either $b<m$ or $a'>a$, one of these inequalities is strict, and the other adventurer's average profit per monster is less than yours.

This proves that if you have the ability to find the optimal strategy for a dungeon, you can leverage that ability to solve arbitrary SAT instances! (Even just *knowing* whether there's a strategy that achieves $1 - \frac1{2n+m+1}$ average profit per monster is enough to know whether the SAT instance is satisfiable.)